# Send email from Delegated account using Python

Tags: python, gmail-api

Is it possible to Send email from Delegated Account With Python Script? I can send email to users using my Regular Gmail account. But I am unable to send email from Delegated Account.

Comment: SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv7\n5.7.14 oTwuQHAU4Z8FFArAeHRZcjqvoGXKkISrcmM88GwnFGaTvNeieA_uMpPsFToGikdTTJZCLG\n5.7.14 5mhSOhefJAc1fUwC4KNTqMbZPLdugU-uhKTLyM04wjo8-2a0QBqPbT0dlQIBnSEqjzQEuN\n5.7.14 I_0HBRaI4CPQxX1JvjgKT_PFU8s6p7jdlPWa85InjDCD-7dIhnohfic4bgY-YfCPH7_SOS\n5.7.14 3FNY7P33tsob7VTl2wmgoR6r_JiJw> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 w18-v6sm20256958pgq.1 - gsmtp')

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. As per [Gmail API Managing delegation settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings):

> Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.